# Net core web API project and Net framework web API project in same Visual Studio solution

Tags: visual-studio, iis-express

I have a VS solution containing two web API projects one net core web API and one net framework web API

How can I launch both web API projects for debugging on IIS express?
I found out that only one web API launches at a time (the one set as Startup project)

In the configuration manager both projects are set to build:
[image]

Comment: What's the version of Visual Studio that you are using? That matters a lot.

Comment: Visual Studio 2019

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At least for VS 2022, you can follow the simplest steps to select multiple projects as startup projects,

[image: Visual Studio multiple startup projects selection]

But one thing to note is that **before setting multiple startup projects, you should debug your ASP.NET Core project at least once and select from the Debug menu to debug upon IIS Express**,

[image: Visual Studio debug menu to select IIS Express]

## Reference

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/how-to-set-multiple-startup-projects?view=vs-2022

Comment: Thanks [@Lex Li], that's exactly what I was missing.